# Parsing output in Qt

Tags: qt, parsing, qprocess

I need to parse the output of `vol` command only to get the id i.e only `abcd-1234`, that is being used in `QProcess`. Here is my code to get the Volume Serial Number:

```
QProcess process;
process.start("cmd /c vol C:");
process.waitForFinished(-1);
QByteArray out = process.readAllStandardOutput();
qDebug() << out;
```

Help me, thanks...

Comment: You could try a little harder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regular expression with QRegExp (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qregexp.html) to find the ID.
The vol command will always return the same message. So, you can read the result line by line and search the matching line:

```
QRegExp rx( "The Volume Serial Number is (.+)\\."); // Match the line with the ID and store it.
if ( rx.exactMatch( line ) {
    QString id = rx.capturedTexts(1); // The first elt is the entire matching text.
    qDebug() << id;
}
```